# Symfony2 : How to update and entity after cancel has been clicked in a form

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, persistence, unbind

I have an form an entity with a cancel button.
My ojective is that when the user clicks on cancel, I ignore ongoing user changes from the form but I update in my controller some of the fields of the same entity.

Here is my issue.
When cancel is clicked, my controller has to handle the request in order to identity that cancel has been clicked. As a result of this my entity is updated with ongoing (but not validated) user changes from the form. I don't know how to discard these changes prior to update some of the fields. Currently whatever I am doing, my entity is updated with ongoing user changes and persisting the data will persist both user changes and my controller updates.

```
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $change = $em->getRepository('psmdbBundle:changes')->find($id);

    $notification = $this->container->get('notification');

    if (!$change) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find changes entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($change);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    // Manage Cancel Button
    if ($editForm->get('cancel')->isClicked()) {

        //Cancel is clicked
        if (!$change->getSaved()) {
            // A change was just created
            $em->remove($change);
            $em->flush();
            $notification->notify('cancel');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_changes'));
        } else {
            // A change was already existing
            // TODO undo user changes as cancel has been clicked before resetting Futurerequest and Futurerequiredapproval
            $change->setFuturerequest('');
            $change->setFuturerequiredapproval('');
            $em->persist($change);
            $em->flush();
            $notification->notify('cancel');
            return $this->redirect($this-> generateUrl('admin_changes_show', array('id' => $id)));
        }
// Rest of the controller...
```

I have tried things such as instantiating another variable like $changeBack but it still retrieves ongoing user changes :

```
$changeBack = $em->getRepository('psmdbBundle:changes')->find($id);
```

So after the controller identifies the Cancel case, is there a way to 'unbind' the entity from the form ? Or to get a instance of the entity from the database ?

One solution I envisage is to handle Cancel button through JS but I would have liked to understand how I can do that in Symfony.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple `submit` buttons and then determine in your controller which one was clicked. So, if you make your `Cancel` button a `submit` button, you could use `isClicked` method to recognize that `Cancel` button was clicked, and act accordingly, i.e. repopulate/refresh `$change`:

```
if ($editForm->get('cancel')->isClicked()) {
    $em->detach($change); // detaching
    $change = $em->getRepository('psmdbBundle:changes')->find($id); // repopulating
    //...
}
```

Or, as @Cerad noted, the entity could be refreshed. Detaching and repopulating is not really necessary:

```
if ($editForm->get('cancel')->isClicked()) {
     $em->refresh($change); // refreshing
    //...
}
```

More info in docs - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-submitting-multiple-buttons

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried this but even if I retrieve $change from the repository, it it seems to come from the entity not from the database so the data as submitted from the form...

Comment: That is because `Doctrine` caches your entity. Try to detach it before retrieving new copy.

Comment: No need to detach or find again, $em->refresh($change) will do the trick. http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html

Comment: Oh great! the refresh method is what was missing. I had spent some time looking at the API on the form side to see if we could unbind but not (enough) on the entity manager side.

Comment: One admin question there...
As the answer is in a comment what should I do? Post my answer and accept it or wait for @Cerad to to post and then I accept his answer? Thanks

Comment: Let @dmnptr update his answer and then accept it.  He was 95% there.